# Access program specific clipboard data in OSX using Applescript

Tags: applescript, clipboard

I'm looking for an easy way to get and set clipboard data from Final Cut Pro X using Applescript.

In Applescript accessing the clipboard is as simple as

```
set someText to the clipboard
```

and

```
set the clipboard to someText
```

However when the data on the clipboard is from Final Cut Pro X, there doesn't seem to be a way from Applescript to get this data.

I used the [ClipboardViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) to discover that the data on the clipboard is in fact mostly text data (it looks to be XML). It is a different clipboard item (com.apple.flexo.proFFPasteUTI) than what I would normally see when just dealing with text (public.utf8-plain-text and NSStringPboardType).

Is there any easy way to access this data in Applescript?

Comment: XML != text. You could try using `the clipboard as data`; if that gives you the raw XML data you can write it to a temp file (as data) then use System Events' XML Suite to process it. Bear in mind though that the XML format used is almost certainly private and undocumented, so no guarantees it will be stable or useful. Also, if you're copying textual content from an app, it really should provide the data in multiple formats, including degenerate portable formats such as RTF and plain text, in which case `the clipboard as text` should work. Though I suspect FCP is a bit of a law unto itself.

Comment: I tried `the clipboard as data` and it gives me `error "Can’t make some data into the expected type." number -1700 to item`. 

If I can find a way to read and write this data, I can probably get around FCPX's lack of hotkeys for many tasks. I'd like to read the data and automate a way to match the duration of a overlay with the duration of the clip on in the sequence when pasting from the clipboard.

Comment: You could also try `pbpaste` in Terminal; see if that provides a better result. If not, you'll likely have to dive into Cocoa and work with `NSPasteboard` directly, either using ObjC/Swift or via the AppleScriptObjC bridge. (Or, hey, you could find yourself a professional video editing application that doesn't live or die on the whims and vagaries of a consumer products company.:p)

Comment: I would have never considered using FCPX but it's what my boss has us use (he got a deal in two ways: (1) his editors become proficient in a software that nobody else uses (2) he got a screaming deal for volume licensing FCPX). I tried `pbpaste` and it gives me the same result (returns an empty clipboard). There may be some `pbpaste` parameters I'm overlooking?  `NSPasteboard` sounds like a good option, but I have little experience in Cocoa. The idea of doing it via the AppleScriptObjC bridge sounds appealing. I'll give that a try next.

Comment: Get your employer to buy you a copy of Shane Stanley's Everyday AppleScriptObjC (http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/everyday_book.html). It'll pay for itself in man-hours saved in no time.